# Reverse for 'update_profile' not found. 'update_profile' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-models

I hope you're well. Just one question that's been bothering me a lot lately...
I got the issue only when I update my form. The update works after refreshing the page.

views.py in user folder

```
#update detail
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/earlycooker/login/'),name="dispatch")
class UserProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    template_name = 'profile-update.html'
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    success_message = "Profile updated"


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return super(UserProfileUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('update_profile',kwargs={'slug':self.object.slug})
    
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if self.object.user != request.user:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        
        return super(UserProfileUpdateView, self).get(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

urls.py in user folder

```
path('details/<slug:slug>/', UserProfileUpdateView.as_view(), name="update_profile"),
```

profile-update.html in user folder

```
{% url 'user:update_profile' slug=user.userprofile.slug %}
```

Comment: Do you think `return reverse('update_profile',kwargs={'slug':self.object.slug})` should be `return reverse('user:update_profile',kwargs={'slug':self.object.slug})`

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score -1):

From this `'user:update_profile'` ,The application name (app_name) of the `update_profile` url is `user`.

```
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/earlycooker/login/'),name="dispatch")
class UserProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    template_name = 'profile-update.html'
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    success_message = "Profile updated"


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return super(UserProfileUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('user:update_profile',kwargs={'slug':self.object.slug})
    
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if self.object.user != request.user:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        
        return super(UserProfileUpdateView, self).get(request,*args,**kwargs)
```